# Laravel get parent attributes

Tags: laravel

I started working on a small project, i have two models Building & Apartment, each Building can have many apartments.

so i have created a relationship between the models but i get an error when i try to access to the parent **( Building )**

This is my models :

// `Building.php`

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Apartment;

class Building extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function apartment(){
        return $this->hasMany(Apartment::class);
    }
}
```

// `Apartment.php`

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Building;

class Apartment extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function building(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Building::class);
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Apartment;
use App\Building; 

public function index()
{
    $apartment = Apartment::with('building')->get();
    return $apartment->building;
}
```

Error Message : `Property [building] does not exist on this collection instance.`

I would like to get result like that :

```
Building 1
   Apartment A
   Apartment b

Building 2
   Apartment A
```

Apartment b

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-models  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the get method gets an apartment collection should only get an apartment and then get the building from it.

```
public function index()
{
    $apartment = Apartment::with('building')->first();
    return $apartment->building;
}
```

The `get` method returns an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` containing the results where each result is an instance of the PHP `stdClass` object. You may access each column's value by accessing the column as a property of the object:

```
$apartaments = Apartment::with('building')->get();

foreach ($apartments as $apartament) {
    echo $apartament->building;
}
```

Comment: how can i get an array contains   
Building A
    Apartment 1

Comment: You have to make a SQL query with [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries)